# DatabaseChangeNotification is not triggering when blob content is updated

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I updated blob in Database, DatabaseChangeNotification  has to trigger but it's not happening.

Working fine with normal string/varchar but it's not working with blob.
I am trying as below

```
OracleConnection conn = connect();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS,"true");
    prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,"true");
    DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = conn.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);
    try {
        DCNDemoListener list = new DCNDemoListener(this);
        dcr.addListener(list);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TEST_MODEL");
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();          
        ResultSet rss = stmt.executeQuery("select TESTSUITE_NAME,TESTSUITE_DEFINITION from TESTSUITE_MODELS");
        while (rss.next()) {
            System.out.println(rss.getString("TESTSUITE_NAME"));
            System.out.println(rss.getBlob("TESTSUITE_DEFINITION"));
        }
        rss.close();
        stmt.close();
```

Can anyone help me in this?

If I am  trying to query table which conatian blob column I am getting "ORA-29977: Unsupported column type for query registration in guaranteed mode for blolb" exception

ResultSet rss = stmt.executeQuery("select TESTSUITE_NAME,TESTSUITE_DEFINITION from TESTSUITE_MODELS");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used database change notification (thanks for the hint, looks quite interesting!), but found the following in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm#CHDEHADG):

> To be registered for QRCN in **guaranteed mode**, a query must conform to the following rules:
>   Every column that it references is either a `NUMBER` data type or a `VARCHAR2` data type.

The section about QRCN in **best effort mode** seems not to have this restriction.

Does anybody know how to use the best effort mode from JDBC?

Comment: Excellent! How did you change to best effort mode?

Comment: i set  OracleConnection.DCN_BEST_EFFORT as true